# C#:How to get the name/nuber of the curent PowerPoint slide and send it via Serial port?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I want create an small app that open a .ppt file (PowerPoint) and check at what slide the file is , i want to send the current number/name of slide to COM4 Serial Port .

Example :
If the Power point have 30 slides and i`m at 21 , the app have to send 21 to the serial port ...

The problem is that i dont know how to check the curent slide from C# .
The Serial Port comunication is done .

Can some one tell me what function i have to use to make my c# app check the current .ppt slide ?Or in what library i have to search .....

Comment: You won't get any answers, as 1.) You ask multiple questions 2.) are not very specific of what you tried and where your problem lies 3.) We're not going to do your work, when you don't put any effort to solve it yourself

Comment: i `m not asking for the app , i`m asking the command to check the current slide in power point , i have  already the SerialPort comunication done , i just dont have idea  in what librarie have to serch for the curent slide function ..

Comment: .ppt does not have any information about the current slide you are on this is something the program that opens the file does. Therefore this is not possible.

Comment: What if you have multiple instances of PowerPoint open?

Comment: There is no way to tell from the ppt file itself which slide is showing - regardless of the client and number of clients. You have to add your code  to the application showing the ppt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal/slide/slide sorter view use:
`Activewindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex`

For the current slide in slide show view use:

`SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition`

or

`SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex`

For the master views slide index isn't applicable so check the `Activewindow.View.Type`.

Comment: I would add that these are vba instructions, so they must run inside ppt

Comment: Yes, @R2xT can update it to work with c# just as easily.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart:  PowerPoint only allows one instance of itself to be open at a time, so for the most part, multiple instances is a non-issue.  There might be multiple presentations open within one instance of PowerPoint or if you create an instance of PPT, you might get a new instance or you might get an already-running instance with other presentations open.  So you've raised a good point, and it's worth checking on this stuff.